# Slim 3: best way to pass variables (that depends on request) to layout?

Tags: twig, middleware, slim-3

I need to pass variable to a Twig layout about user country and language.

These datas are determined from the route, so I can't get them before routing is done.

I could set them from the route callbacks but code would be repeated in each route.

So I added a middleware to routes. It reads request arguments and sets variables (through `$twig->getEnvironment()->addGlobal(...)`).

I am not fully convinced, is there a better way to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: There are a lots of way to achieve this, depending on how your app is made, I personally use a middleware (not added to route) to check request URI and search for my language var, by this way I code only one middleware and not one per language.
For view variable you can add a global var like you do or just like this `$app->view['varname'] = $var`

Comment: global twig vars are really present in all twig templates that use the twig env you get from `$twig->getEnvironment()`; if you are sure that you will need them in all templates, than yes, that is why twig globals were made. Otherwise you should just pass them "manually" via the `render` function

Comment: actually, my interrogation is on using a middleware to pass the vars to Twig, is it OK or is there a better option